# How read the content of a volume in Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to find the content of my volumes. I have make docker volume inspect and follow the mountpoint but the file or directory doesn't exist. How please can I read the data inside my volumes ?

Comment: How are you running your container?  What Docker environment are you using (Toolbox, For Windows, For Mac, native on Linux)?  Why do you need to?

Comment: I'm running my containers in a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 environment on my local desktop all in local, no virtual machine, Docker installed on local,  I just want to view my data on the volume passing directly by the system

Comment: Can you provide more details such as how did you run docker containers, images used, how did you set up volumes, docker-compose file, if you used one etc...?